# iOS CNA on iOS 10.3 does not open links in Safari

Tags: ios, ios10, captivenetwork, captiveportal

I have a router that opens the Apple CNA on a captive portal with a button to accept the terms & conditions

When the users accept the terms, the router unlocks the connection and redirect the user to a welcome page with a link.

On iOS 10.2.1 when I click on the link (it is an absolute link "https://mydomain.it/mypage") the CNA is automatically close and Safari is opened with the link.

On iOS 10.3.1 the link is opened inside the CNA with all limitations of the case (limited js support, no localstorage, ecc...)

How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the top left button "Done" when you click on the link, or is it still "Cancel"? Are you sure you don't have timing issues? Have you tried using a different domain (or sub-domain)?

Comment: the button is "Done", when the link appears the modem has already unlocked the Internet. In the same identical configuration my iPhone with 10.2.1 opens it in Safari

Comment: Don't see anything in release notes for a related change. I see other people have the same issue on the Apple Developer Forum and you already posted there. You'll probably have to contact developper support or file a bug report.

Comment: I filled a bug report now...

Comment: Same issue in 10.3.2

Comment: @MattiaLancieri did you get any update on this? I too have only just noticed this issue on 10.3.2

Comment: @MattiaLancieri did you end-up filing a bug report? Can I have the link? Any update?

Comment: I updated the bug report, but is closed because is a duplicate of another

Comment: I fill the bug report #35059606 for this problem, relative to iOS 11.0.3

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed in one of the iOS 11 beta, but in the iOS 11 GM released yesterday there is another issue: the CNA does not close itself after it opens a link in Safari. Users need to close the CNA by tapping the "Done" button themselves.

Comment: same issue in 11.0.3

Comment: I fill the bug report #35059606 for this